# nicEdit:Icons and tooltips are wrong

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, nicedit

I have implemented nicEdit on a site. For some reason, the icons and the tooltips are wrong. If you click on the Bold icon it inserts an horizontal rule.

Any clue on this?

[image]

Comment: are the rest correct or is it all of them?

Comment: Why you are using this? There is other like tinymce and ckeditor that have been developed for years..

Comment: nicedit is configurable anyway https://philihp.com/blog/2009/converting-a-date-to-a-datetime-in-sas/

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
The rest is incorrect as well.
I'm using this one because is easy to implement and fit my needs.

BTW, the link you provides is about Converting between Date and Datetime in SAS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outdated icons file.

The image file called NicEditIcons.